# Locus of a moving point, such that two distances have a common ratio

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, locus

A, B are two fixed points on a fixed circle; P is a variable point on the circle; Q is a point on BP, such that BQ/AP is constant; find the locus of Q.

The only approach I could think of is through coordinate geometry. Consider the unit circle centred at the origin, fix B at (1,0) and denote points A and P by the angle they make with the x-axis. Then we can calculate AP and the line BP. But the calculations are tedious, and I have not been able to complete them.

Is there a more elegant method? A complete solution using the coordinate geometry method would also be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What about for when $P$ coincides with $B$? Q is not defined then, right?

Comment: I think you're talking about when P coincides with A? I guess we have to ignore that.

Comment: It would be a pair of circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rather elegant solution to this, but requires some construction, and would be difficult to include in an answer, but I shall try my best.

[image]

Now, in the above diagram, $P$ is the moving point, and $C$ replaces $A$ in your question (sorry about that, software is new to me). When you deflect $P$ w.r.t to $CP'$ by $\theta$, the length of $CP = 2r\cos\theta$

Now, we know that $BQ = k.CP$ from the condition of our problem, hence

$$BQ = 2kr \cos \theta$$
$$BQ' = 2kr$$

Hence, we will always have

$$BQ = BQ' \cos \theta$$

And since $Q'$ is a fixed point for a given $C$ and $B$, this would be a circle. Actually a pair, because it could be on either side of $BP$. I hope this answers your question